# Control Flow in PHP

Tags: php

I am new to php, I am currently facing problem using header function.

Currently I am working on a ticketing system, in which when all of the user credentials are validated he is redirected to the payment gateway. On successful payment completion I have to redirect him back to the the page where validation was done. I am using header function to do this. My concern is how is the call stack when header function is called, I am not able to visualize the call stack do i need to manage it or php does it on its own.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Put your redirection logic at the top of your script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: My question was how to manage the call stack and I was not concerned about header ob_start was something I didn't knew.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing special about how `header` is called. It's a function just like any other.

*However*, due to the way output is sent to the browser, it is essential that any `header` calls be made before any output is sent. Any at all. Not even a single space is allowed. Personally, I achieve this effect with `ob_start()`, however be aware that doing so prevents longer pages from being downloaded in pieces - they must be processed to completion before they are sent. In my case, that's not a problem, because my pages generate in less than a tenth of a second.

Keep in mind, however, that just because you use `header` to start a redirect, that does *not* stop the rest of the script from being executed. You will almost always want to `exit;` immediately after the `header` call.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope I answered your question!